# How to apply a filter computed property to a computed property inside Vuex's mapState?

Tags: vue.js, redux, vuex

I have a list of shipments correctly being rendered into the DOM. Such an array of shipments is defined like this inside the component:

```
computed: mapState([
    'shipments'
])
```

Now I want to filter the array based on certain criteria. I had this perfectly implemented before inserting Vuex into the app. The computed property that used to do this before, looks like this:

```
filteredShipments() {
   // Some processing

   let filtered = arr.filter(shipment => shipment.criteria);
   return filtered;
}
```

What's the correct syntax to filter `shipments`based on `filteredShipments()`?

Comment: You still can use a computed prop filteredShipments in your template that filters this.shipments and returns filtered array

Comment: Why not to create a getter in the vuex itself?

Comment: @Anatoly I'm getting this error: method "filteredShipments" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. 


I'm trying this syntax:

  computed: mapState([
        'shipments',
    ]),
      filteredShipments() {
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. This is solved with the spread operator:

```
computed: {
   ...mapState([
      'shipments'
   ]),
   filteredShipments() { 
       // logic
   }
}
```